# Adding active class based on current URL

Tags: javascript, classname

I am trying to add 'active' class on my link. It is saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).each is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
const current = window.location.href;
document.querySelectorAll("#nav-tab a").each(function(){
    const $this = this;
    
    if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
        $this.classList.add("active");
    }
});
```

Can you help me? Or is there a better way to add a class name based on the current URL?
Thank you so much!

Comment: It is [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) not `.each()` (provided that your browser supports `.forEach()`)

Comment: Try with `forEach` `document.querySelectorAll("#nav-tab a").forEach(function(){`

Comment: Hey @NickParsons and @angel.bonev! Thanks guys that worked! 
Now I have a new error that says:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attr')` hmmm

Comment: @ddd you're confusing jQuery methods with regular DOM methods. You want to us [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), not `.attr()` (even using `.href` should work)

Comment: @NickParsons ohh my bad!! I used `getAttribute()` but have the same error. I think this is probably I am getting `undefined` value when I do `console.log()` on `$this`

Comment: @ddd oh yep, `this` inside of your function also isn't going to be the lement. You want to access the element in your function using the argument of the function `function(elem) {`, then call your methods on `elem` instead of `$this`

Comment: @NickParsons. You're the best!! Do you want to write your answer? So I can vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code. Your mainly confusing jQuery methods with regular native browser methods/conventions:

1. You need to use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and not `.each()`. The `.forEach()` method is a method on the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns.
2. `.attr()` is not a valid method. To get an element's attribute you can use [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute). We can use `.href` here instead to get the href. Note that `getAttribute("href")` will retrieve the URL as it is in your mark-up, whereas `.href` will retrieve the full, eg, if you had `href="/foo/bar"`, `.href` will give `https://example.com/foo/bar`, whereas `.getAttribute()` will return just `/foo/bar`.
3. Use the element parameter of the function instead of `this`. When you use `.forEach()` you're iterating over the elements in your NodeList (ie: the elements you selected), so you can access each using the first parameter of the `forEach` callback. The `this` value in the browser (if not in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context)) will default to `window`, so it won't be the element like you're expecting it to be:

```js
const current = window.location.href;
document.querySelectorAll("#nav-tab a").forEach(function(elem){ 
    if(elem.href.includes(current)){
      elem.classList.add("active");
    }
});
```

I've also changed `.indexOf(...) !== -1` to [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), which is a more modern way to check if a string contains another value.

---

I will point out that you can make your query selector more advanced, which will limit the number of elements you iterate:

```js
const current = window.location.href;
document.querySelectorAll(`#nav-tab a[href*="${current}"]`).forEach(elem => { 
  elem.classList.add("active");
});
```

This uses the attribute selector [`a[href*=...]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#syntax) to select the `a` elements that have a `href` that contains the text in stored in `current`.

Comment: Thank you for helping and for explaining, @Nick Parsons!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mistaken jQuery and vanilla javascript

[$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is a jQuery function in you case you can use [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accessing_the_matches)

[$.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery function in you case you can use [.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```js
const current = "#test-3";//window.location.href;
document.querySelectorAll("#nav-tab a").forEach((elem) => {
    if (elem.getAttribute('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
        elem.classList.add("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.active { color:red}
```

```html
<div id="nav-tab">
    <a href="#test-1">Test 1</a>
    <a href="#test-2">Test 2</a>
    <a href="#test-3">Test 3</a>
    <a href="#test-4">Test 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @angel.bonev!! Right, I confused jQuery with Vanilla JS!

Comment: @ddd You're welcome. It happens to me in my early programming years. I know the feeling. Cheers